# How can I replace the example value for a field in spring doc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm trying to add a Springdoc/Swagger interface to my existing REST services in SpringBoot. The objects that I have to deal with (which I can't change) contain circular references. In order to deal with the circular references, we're using JsonIO to serialize/deserialize the objects. As an example, I have a class called Part that looks like the following:

```
public class Part
{
  // Other fields etc removed for brevity

  private Part parent;

  // methods removed for brevity
}
```

The parent field is a circular reference back to the same object type. When Springdoc creates an example for one of my REST method parameters, it generates the following:

```
{
  "parent" : "string"
}
```

which defines the parent field in my class as a String rather than an actual reference to my Part class. What I'd ideally like to do is to have the "parent" value forced to be a null object (or an empty object would probably work as well.) Unfortunately I have been unable to figure out how I'd go about this, especially without access to the Part class source (so I can't add annotations, etc).

Is this possible, and if so how can I make this work?